# Test assertion fail

Tags: python, file-handling

I've wrote a function which export dictionary as a string into csv file.
In my assignment I'm instructed to export this dict as one string (I took keys from dict and separated them with commas - no spaces). I have a file which test this function - I'm here so of course it fails. However when I print output of that function it looks like in my assignment e.g sth1,sth2,sth3,sth4. What I'm missing here?
Here is my code:

```
def export_stock(stock, filename="export.csv"):

with open(filename, "w+") as exportation:
    a = list(stock.keys())
    a = ",".join(a)
    exportation.write(a)
```

and here is test func:

```
def test_export(self):
    export_stock({'sth1': 3, 'sth2': 1, "sth3": 1},
                     "export.csv")

    with open("export.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
        expected = ["sth1", "sth2", "sth3", "sth1", "sth1"]
        expected.sort()
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in reader:
            row.sort()
            self.assertListEqual(expected, row)
```

Comment: Why does your `expected` list have `"sth1"` in it 3 times?

Comment: And why are you reading from a different file from what you wrote to?

Comment: I've mispronounced file should have the same name but test still fails

Comment: That's because your program isn't doing what your assignment wants. I assume it wants you to look at the value attached to the key, then repeat the key that number of times in the row. Since 'sth1' has a value of 3, it should be repeated three times.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in the filename `test_stock_export.csv` when you call your function, so it will export the results to that file. In your test, you open `export.csv` and check for the results in there. I think you meant to open `test_stock_export.csv` in your test.